# Prove the coefficient of $x^2$ is the sum.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> In the expansion: $(1 + ax)(1 + bx)(1+cx) \cdots$ find the general coefficient of $x^2$ and prove the formula.

Consider $(1 + ax)(1 + bx)$, the coefficient of $x^2$ is: $ab$.

Consider $(1 + ax)(1+bx)(1+cx)$, the coefficient of $x^2$ is: $ab + bc + ca$.

Consider $(1 + ax)(1 + bx)(1+cx)(1+dx)$, the coefficient of $x^2$ is: $ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd$.

I can see the pattern that: $$Cx^2 \implies C = \sum_{\text{cyclic, number of variables}} ab$$

How do I begin to construct a proof however? I just need a general idea, not a full answer?

Comment: hint: show that the coefficient of $x$ is $a+b+c+d+\dots$, then use induction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also think of this as a function of $f(y) = (y+ax)(y+bx)(y+cx)(...)$ for $f(1)$. If we regard $x$ and $y$ as variables, each term will have the same degree. If we let $\deg(f)=n$ and we have $\deg(x)+\deg(y)=n$ and the coefficient of $x^2$ is the same as the coefficient of $y^{n-2}$. Thus, the answer can be given to us by Vieta's Relations as the second symmetric sum.

Another way to think about this is the fact that a power of $x$ can only appear if and only if it is coupled with another constant (a letter other than $x$), so if $x$ has a power of two, it must have two constants $(a,b,c,...)$. For every two-element subset of $(a,b,c,...)$ we have a coefficient of $x^2$, so it follows that the coefficient of $x^2$ is every possible product of two-element subsets of $(a,b,c,...)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Consider the product

$$(1+a_1x)(1+a_2x)\ldots(1+a_nx)\;.$$

Before collecting terms, each term of the product is obtained by choosing one term of each of the $n$ binomial factors and multiplying them. The result is an $x^2$ term if and only if exactly two of the factors contribute an $x$ term rather than a $1$ term. Thus, you get one $x^2$ term for each ...